# SQL noob, how to join two tables and store data into a new_table?

Tags: sql, join, datatable, inner-join

I have two tables that i want to join(in terms of symbol and date(only the YEAR have to match!!))  and store in a new_table, is that possible?

expected result:

```
symbol       date 1             value 1          date 2             value 2

"A"          "2010-12-31"       "29.635193133"   "2010-01-05"       "22.324748927"
```

1.

```
symbol   date           value_1
"A"     "2010-12-31"    "29.635193133"
"A"     "2011-12-30"    "24.985693133"
"A"     "2012-12-31"    "29.284693133"
"AAL"   "2010-12-31"    "10.01"
"AAL"   "2011-12-30"    "5.07"
```

and 2.

```
symbol   date           value_2
"A"     "2010-01-05"    "22.324748927"
"A"     "2011-01-05"    "29.5135915594"
"AAL"   "2012-01-05"    "5.15"
"AAL"   "2015-01-05"    "54.369999"
```

Comment: I don't understand your data/question.

Comment: amazing expected result.

Comment: which sql version? mysql or sql-server?

Comment: "store in a new table" is often an anti-pattern as you are duplicating data. You can easily re-run a query whenever you need the answer again. What if the data in Table1 or Table2 changes? Does it invalidate Table3? Do you have to refresh it? If so, you are running the query again anyway! There can be reasons (performance, reporting, auditing etc) for keeping a separate copy, but think carefully first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably more issues to resolve, but here is a solution:

```
create table table3 as 
select *
from table1
inner join table2 
on symbol1 = symbol2
and year(date1) = year(date2)
```

Working example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2cdf4f/1